# Scenarios in which NSURLErrorCannotFindHost can occur in iOS webview

Tags: ios, dns, uiwebview

I am an embedded programmer,but now am trying to analyze iOS logs for an issue where webview fails to load an URL. From the logs, I see the following

```
404230 (_:didStartProvisionalNavigation:)::Entry 
404230 (_:didStartProvisionalNavigation:)::Exit 
404250 (_:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:)::Entry
404250 (_:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:)::server with the specified hostname could not be found
404250 (_:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:)::Exit
```

It is observed that `didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError` is called within 20 milliseconds after `didStartProvisionalNavigation` with error as NSURLErrorCannotFindHost.

So following are my questions:

1. Based on the timing between `didStartProvisionalNavigation` and
   `didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError`, I am starting to wonder if
   webview actually tried to resolve the domain name. Is this timing
   normal, what is the default DNS lookup timeout?
2. In what other circumstances will this error happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iOS webview tried to resolve the domain name, the DNS server returned `Standard query response, Refused` (Checked that in wireshark) which is why webview reported the error `NSURLErrorCannotFindHost`.

Apparently since it is an DNS error, it invoked the callback `_:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError` few milliseconds after `_:didStartProvisionalNavigation`. Had it been timeout, it might have taken longer.